# flask app mail password insecure if developed on docker

Tags: python-3.x, docker, security, flask

I am deploying a flask app that is intended to be run locally but I need to send some mails within it and so to provide the app mail address username and password. I know I can pass them as secret env variables but the problem is that everyone that will download and run the image would be able to access them, e.g. accessing the running docker and modifying the script adding something like (`create_app` is the function I use to create the app instance):

```py
docker container exec -it app /bin/bash
source venv/bin/activate
python
from app import create_app
app = create_app()
print( app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] )
```

Is there any safe way to protect such sensible data in order for the docker to have it but making them not retrievable at all from users?

Comment: Maybe create a service account that can be shared? Otherwise, it might be best to avoid checking-in the credentials.

Comment: Passing environment variables at container startup time is a typical approach.  You should not usually need `docker exec` in normal operation.